# Where are the new membership providers classes in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, migration, asp.net-identity

I'm migrating from the old aspnet_membership tables to the newer ASP.NET Identity.

I've followed the steps [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity).

Except in step 1 I did not create a new application but started with my existiug application, which should come down to the same.

Where I get confused is at step `Creating models and membership pages`.

In my current application I have classes like:

- `MembershipProvider.vb`
- `RoleProvider.vb`
- `ProfileProvider.vb`

These contain a ton of methods, such as `CreateUser`, `ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer`, `ResetPassword` etc. So everything needed to handle user administration, but they connect to the old table structure.

Where are these classes and methods in the new ASP.NET Identity implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserManager` is the class you want for users CRUD. `RoleManager` is for CRUD related to roles.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But where do I find the codefiles for these classes? I need to know how they save data to the db and want to extend some of them with my own logic. I'd expected some custom classes/codefiles to be added to my solution? Or is everything already compiled and if so, under which namespace could I find the classes and methods?

Comment: This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics - scroll down to title "Application User Manager and Application Role Manager"

Comment: And source code for current Identity is here: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Readme.markdown

Comment: Ah, thanks.Before I start my (complex) upgrade to Identity1.0, I'm correct that Identity1.0 will also serve as an authorization server? I need that as I have existing user accounts that need to be able to login with their email address and password.

Comment: 1) Identity 2.2 is released for some time now, it is much better than 1.0, so use it. 2) Not sure what you mean by "authorisation server", but you can migrate existing users from MembershipProvider into Identity.

Comment: I was reading this: http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-build-a-Nodejs-rest-api-with-oauth2. Start reading the 2 paragraphs after "They are distinct from a service which uses OAuth to authenticate a user". Does that clarify what I need?

Comment: No, Identity is not OAuth server, though I believe there is a project IdentityServer3

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm really surprised at the amount of effort it takes to setup something like oAuth with an existing userbase. I'll have a look at it.